# Do disconnects count against the rounds remaining for food effects?

Tags: splatoon-3

Let's say I have a bonus food effect active that lasts for 20 rounds. If a match I'm in gets disbanded due to a player disconnecting, will that count against the rounds remaining before the food effect runs out?

[image: disconnect message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently (and sadly), yes.

> The most annoying thing is that players will lose their food and drink ticket uses if they disconnect. Or, if another player disconnects at the start and you’re all kicked out.

[Source](https://gamingintel.com/server-communication-errors-disconnects-plague-splatoon-3/).